# If there are 2 replicas do they need to be in 2 seperate nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 2 node cluster for Elastic search and the health is in yellow. It looks like there are 10 primary shards and 2 replicas (i.e 2 reaplicas per primary shard so that mean 20 replica shards). If primay is in node1 and can all the replicas be in node 2 or will we need a node 3 for the second replica. I did read that ES does not place replica in the same node as the primay. so does if there a 2 replicas can it place in the same node (node2) or the second one has to be place in node 3

```
health status index              uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   sdfs_v4         D2BpVICsddShJay_iz1FBQ    10   2     870293        28005      7.8gb          3.8gb
yellow open   abc_v4        nd-5fffsbcvcxxCqZPVNMCQ     10   2     396914       205632      2.7gb          1.3gb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works is that a primary and any replica cannot be on the same node. So in a two nodes cluster, if the primary is on node1, one replica can be on node2, and all other replicas are unassigned.

The maximum number of replicas you can have is `number of nodes - 1`. In your case, having two replicas for each primary in a two-nodes cluster doesn't make sense.

You can either add a new node or decrease the number of replicas.

Comment: thanks for the reply for the replicas to be used as reads do we need to use as  configuration or are the replica once allocated to a node automatically accept reads

Comment: both primary and replicas are read/write, you cannot change that, it's automatic